# Insert xml document to mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to insert a xml file as a string as a entry into mysql. 
However, because of the presence of special characters, I am not able to do.

Is there any function in PHP that converts the xml into a format compatible with mysql query.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mysql_real_escape_string();